# Method returning true or false depending on whether a name exists with that respective first name

Tags: java

I have created a simple program with a register (List) called `reg`. I have also created a class called `Name` which consists of `firstName` and `familyName`. I have to create a method returning `true` or `false` depending on whether a name exists with that respective first name. For example if there is a name "David Long" and I ask if "David" exists in the List it should return `true`. I have each of these on separate classes and I am confused how to 'link' them. I have `Name`, `Person`, `Register` and `RegisterTest` classes. `RegisterTest` is testing my program while the rest contain code to run it.

I've tried putting something like this into Register class:

```
public boolean existsOrNot(){
    if (names.contains("Tom")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then this into my RegisterTest class where public static void main(String[] args) is:

```
    System.out.println(existsOrNot());
```

This is how my RegisterTest looks like:

```
public class RegisterTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Register reg = new Register();

    reg.addPerson(new Person(new Name("John", "Smith")));
    reg.addPerson(new Person(new Name("Tom", "Morgan")));
    reg.addPerson(new Person(new Name("Robert", "Man")));
    reg.addPerson(new Person(new Name("Jamie", "Young")));
    reg.addPerson(new Person(new Name("David", "Long")));

    System.out.println("People:\n" + reg.toString() + "\n");

    System.out.println("List of people's names:");
    for (int i=0;i < reg.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(reg.getPerson(i).getName().getFullName());
    }

    System.out.println("======================");

    System.out.println("Number of people: " + reg.size());
```

Here's the Register class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Register {

//Fields
private ArrayList<Person> names;


//Constructors
public Register() {
    names = new ArrayList<Person>();
}


//Methods
public void addPerson(Person n) {
    names.add(n);
}

public void removePerson(int pos) {
    names.remove(pos);
}

public Person getPerson(int pos) {
    return names.get(pos);
}

public int size() {
    return names.size();
}

public void clearRegister() {
    names.clear();
}

public boolean isRegisterEmpty() {
    return names.isEmpty();
}

public boolean existsOrNot() {
    if (names.contains("Tom")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return "Register:[name=" + names + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: "I am confused how to 'link' them" - you'll have to be more specific on what you want to achieve here.

Comment: The code I've provided at the top doesn't work. Same with the second one. I just can't get it right. What I mean by 'link' is how should the Register class know I am talking about about reg register from RegisterTest?

Comment: What's the definition of `names` in `existsOrNot()`?

Comment: 'names' is the name for the register of Person.

Comment: Without knowing how `names` is declared and what it contains, how do you expect us to evaluate whether your function does what you want?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your code and question since both are kind of missing, but why don't you provide a parameter in `existsOrNot()` that takes in your ArrayList?

Comment: I'm seriously confused about that. What do you mean by providing a parameter in existsOrNot()?

Comment: The way I'm reading it, your `existsOrNot()` method is checking the global variable of `names`. `names` hasn't even been given a value yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your `names` variable in `Register` is an `ArrayList` of `Person` objects, not of `Name` objects.  It looks like a `Person` is constructed with a `Name`, but a `Person` is not a `Name`.  Therefore the `contains` method is looking for matches on `Person`s, and will never find a match.

You'll need to iterate through the `Person` objects, and peek at each one's `Name` object to see if the first element matches `"Tom"` in order to do what you want.

Comment: Exactly. But how do I do this throughout all the Person objects? I'm new to java and don't really understand this. I'm already looking through 'names' which is an array of Person. If I will look through names I will get every single name from Person array. It still doesn't give me the appropriate answer. It gives me false.

Comment: You do it exactly as I said.  Iterate through the `ArrayList` of `Person`s, and for each `Person` see if its `Name` object contains the target.  If any of them matches the target, immediately return `true`.  If you finish iterating without a match, then return `false` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @pjs, you need to do something like..

```
    public boolean existsOrNot() {
      for (Person person : names){
            if ("Tom".equals(person.getName().getFirstName()){
              return true;
            }
         }
      return false
   }
```

Comment: Somehow the result isn't boolean. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the function in your Register class you need to call it from the object (if that class is static you wouldn't need an instance but still call it from the class)

So that should work in your RegisterTest class

```
System.out.println(reg.existsOrNot());
```

That function in the Register class becomes a function of your reg object.

Comment: Changed it. It returns something now but not the correct answer. "Tom" exists in the reg register but still gives me false.

Comment: Can you add your Register class to the question? Else I can't see the problem

Answer (score -1):

Okay, let's pretend that I didn't write the existsOrNot() function. What would you do to make it work properly because I think my code makes some confusion here.

Comment: Extending your question in an "answer" is not how things work here.

Comment: If I don't understand what you mean I'm trying to at least get your point of view with at least a bit of code on what I'm doing wrong not the entire answer.

Comment: Then put an addendum on your question, or add a comment to the question or to one of the answers.  Don't post your followup or extension question as an answer.